# can you load a new page into a jquery ui dialog with asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, binding

i have a regular html Grid and i am binding my asp.net mvc view to a strongly typed array called **MyObject[]**.  MyObject has 40 properties but i only populate 10 of them because that is what is shown on the main grid.  this is in the index view.

i want to add a column to my grid to have a link that says **"Edit Details"**.  this would bring up jquery ui dialog with a form to fill out and allow the user to edit the details.  i basically want to show my whole edit view inside the jquery ui dialog on top of the index page.

the one issue that i have is there is a lot more data in the details screen than i have brought down from the server.  This was fine when Edit was a seperate page because i went back to the server and populated all the detail data and then did the binding the the edit page but i obviously can't do that now.

So, is there anyway to rebind to a particular **MyObject** that I repopulate from the server or do i have to bring everything down at first and use jquery to populate these fields when i click on the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do a partial post back using jQuery to get the model you want to edit?  then you can return either the model or a RenderParttial and simply display the generated html in the dialog.

if you need samples let me know.

**EDIT**

```
$.post("/Controller/jQueryMethod", { param: paramValue }, function(newCommentListHTML) {
  //do something interesting with the html
});
```

The above will do a jquery post back to your controller and an action called jQueryMethod.

It also passes a single parameter.  Comma seperate these if you want more.

Your controller then grabs the model and it can then pass the model to a PartialView which it then returns.

Much like this return `RenderPartial("PartialView", model);`

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical design pattern and there are numerous ways to accomplish the task. Here is how I would do it:

Add an onclick handler to your edit link, use it to call a javascript function and pass your record id as a parameter. 
Use jQuery's getJSON function to perform an AJAX call to your controller.

```
$.getJSON("/Home/GetDetails/" + yourRecordId, function (data) {
            doSomething(data);
        });
```

Call a method on your controller that returns a JsonResult.

```
    public JsonResult GetDetails(int? id)
    {
        Array MyObject = GetDetails(id)
        return Json(MyObject); // MVC 1.0
        //return Json(MyObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); // MVC 2.0
    }
```

Use the callback function to bind your results and display the details in a modal popup.

This assumes the details will fit on a modal popup. If they don't then I would consider keeping your details in a separate view. A good MVC design takes into account a logical separation of concerns. If your view is actually serving two purposes (i.e. list and edit) then this is an ideal reason to split it into two separate views.

See [ASP.Net MVC Json Result: Parameters passed to controller method issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659858/asp-net-mvc-json-result-parameters-passed-to-controller-method-issue) for more details on passing parameters.

Comment: i have no issues passing parameter back to the server using ajax but what i dont understand is when i get a response, what kicks off the dialog from showing.

Comment: In the above code the doSomething function is registered as a callback event, so it will fire as soon as you get your response from the server. Use this function to kick off your show dialog process.